# how to respond when boss says sorry to disturb you

Tags: expressions

My boss intentionally takes so much time talking about nothing and then says sorry to disturb you in a very sarcastic way. How should I respond to him?

Comment: Please edit the title in your question. The first word should begin with a capital letter, you should use place "your" in front of *boss* and you need a question mark at the end of the sentence to show it is a question. You also misspelled *disturb*.

Comment: Oh, no! The pleasure was all yours.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about workplace etiquette and human relations.

Answer (score 2):

Since he's your boss, the diplomatic thing to say is something on the order "That's OK."

Comment: Dude if the boss **was being sarcastic** then in that case you **absolutely SHOULD NOT** say "that's ok".  That would be being incredibly sarcastic and smart-assed back at the boss!! (Unless that's the effect one wants.)

Comment: Well, Joe, first I think it's possible for an employee to use "that's OK" to respond to a boss's apology with an attitude and demeanor of respect because I don't think the words /by themselves/ inherently convey being sarcastic back to the boss. My answer might be different if I actually heard the exchange myself, because it's not clear to me exactly why OP holds the opinion that boss is being sarcastic, and I'm considering that what the Boss thinks he's saying and how he's saying it may not be what what OP hears him saying, and how the OP hears him saying it.

Comment: fair enough!  (After all, you're the guy with the brass hat! :) ) Indeed it's not clear what was meant. IF the boss was being truly sarcastic (so: the boss was in fact saying "you are not working") you wouldn't give that answer.

Comment: Actually, I would give substantially that answer--"substantially in this" case being "don't worry about it", "no problem", or some other polite phrase, including "that's OK", said with respect and a positive attitude  Even if the boss is sounding sarcastic, it may not be that he or she means to treat you that way; he may have just been dealing with an obnoxious sales person, and forgotten to turn of the "sarcasm switch", and ignoring the sarcasm and replying with respect might just help him or her find and press it. This is an application of "catch more flies with honey than vinegar".

Comment: Let's say you're my boss.  Say I'm slacking off (reading a paperback).  You walk up to me and say, sarcastically: **"Joe, so sorry to disturb you."**  This absolutely and definitely means "Why the hell are you reading a paperback." it does not have any general tone or ambiguity.  it is literally a way of saying - a common formula for saying: "Why the hell are you reading a paperback?".

Comment: Note that you say "it may not be that he or she means ... that."  Sure. Of course that could be the case.

Answer (score 1):

"Absolutely not, my pleasure to help, is there anything more I can help you with?"

Answer (score 1):

Agree with your boss when he apologizes,and say, "Whups! I need to get back to work, because my boss is a real taskmaster, and he's likely to sell me to another plantation if I'm late getting this work done."

But be sure to laugh as you say this.  If he wants to waste your time, well, your time is his. You're just reminding him that it's his fault, not yours, if work doesn't get done in a timely fashion.

So I have a question in return. If someone asks advice about workplace etiquette in a forum devoted to using English properly, should one ignore his question or should one answer his fairly simple question, followed by making rude comments about his mother?

Answer (score 0):

If the boss is truly being sarcastic -- is it the case that you were "fooling around" and not working?

If so, you simply have two choices

(1) Simply apologise.  Say: "Oh, boss, sorry I was [whatever .. looking at Ferraris on the internet]. Tell me what to do next!"

or

(2) Just politely tell him the job is not for you, since you don't get enough free time to [whatever .. looking at Ferraris on the internet].  Walk to the office where you resign from the job.  Collect your personal belongings and leave the building. Become a freelancer.

---

Footnote - you say "boss intentionally takes so much time talking".  Unfortunately s/he can do whatever they want - it's their money. :/